# Spring data JPA save and updating parent entity

Tags: java, spring-boot, eclipse, hibernate, jpa

I have two entities called Student and Subject. They are stored in tables in the following format

| student_id | name | grade |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John | 1 |

| subject_id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | English |
| 2 | Math |

| subject_id | student_id | mark |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 75 |
| 2 | 1 | 75 |

```
**Student:**

@Table(name = "student")
@Data
public class Student {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "grade")
    private int grade;

    //getters and setters left out for this example
}

**Subject:**

@Table(name = "subject")
@Data
public class Subject {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    //getters and setters left out for this example
}

**StudentRepository:**

public interface StudentRepository extends JpaRepository<Student, Long> {
}
```

How do I make it so that everytime I add a student using a StudentController, the subjects are automatically added to the student.

Answer (score 0):

Create the third entity for the third table, create the student object and the subject object . put it in the third entity object, create the third repository and save that, all three tables will be updated together. Just make sure your relationships are correctly mentioned and you are done.

Comment: Ohh so i dont need the student repo but only the subjectstudent repo?

Comment: Can u please elaborate on this maybe example of the third entity and the add controller

Answer (score 0):

Update your Student entity to encapsulate Subject.
The idea is to explicitly define relationship between Student and Subject , and further leverag `Cascade` to propagate changes :

```
@Table(name = "student")
@Data
public class Student {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "grade")
    private int grade;

    @OneToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REMOVE, CascadeType.MERGE}, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinColumn(name = "SUBJECT_ID")
    Subject subject;
}
```

Note : You  need to make sure that you populate Subject when storing Student.

For more clarity , explore the examples presented here : https://vladmihalcea.com/a-beginners-guide-to-jpa-and-hibernate-cascade-types/

Comment: Uhm what do u mean populate my subject can i have an example? Thank you

Comment: @DanielPads 
`Student student=new Student();`
`student.setSubject(<subject you want to create/update with the above student>);`

This way when you persist student , subject will also get persisted.
I would suggest you go through the link provided.It has proper examples for your use case.

Comment: Im not adding a subject just simply adding the subjects in the database to the new student

Comment: Like when i add a student the remarks table will be populated like this subject_id [ 1,2] student_id[2,2]